# How to combine a Gantt chart with scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, gantt-chart

I am trying to visualise a series of points on top of a Gantt chart. The result would look like this using *sns.stripplot* and *plt.barh*

[image]

My issue is that so far I am only able to produce each figure separately and place them one over the other manually, when I tried to combine my plots within the same figure you can see that the scatter plot is not aligned with corresponding step (bar):

[image]

Here is the code to create the 2 dataframes ("df" used for the scatter" and "df_gantt" for the gantt chart):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

# Set the number of rows and columns
num_rows = 10
num_cols = 3

# Create a dictionary of columns with random data
np.random.seed(12345)
data = {f"Step {i}": np.random.uniform(low=0, high=5, size=num_rows) for i in range(1, num_cols + 1)}

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


# Create the Gantt DataFrame
num_steps = num_cols
df_gantt = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Step', 'Start', 'End', 'Duration'])

for i in range(1, num_steps + 1):
    start = 0 if i == 1 else df_gantt.loc[i - 2, 'End']
    duration = np.random.randint(low=5, high=21)
    end = start + duration
    df_gantt = df_gantt.append({'Step': i, 'Start': start, 'End': end, 'Duration': duration}, ignore_index=True)


df_gantt.columns = ['Milestone','start_num','end_num','days_start_to_end']
df_gantt.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
df_gantt['days_start_to_end_cum'] = df_gantt['days_start_to_end']
df_gantt['days_start_to_end_cum'] = df_gantt['days_start_to_end_cum'].cumsum()
df_gantt


# add the steps distance to the original dataframe

for col_idx, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    # get the corresponding row from df_gantt
    row = df_gantt.iloc[col_idx]

    # add the value of days_start_to_end to the column
    df[col] += row['days_start_to_end_cum']

df
```

And here is the code used to create the second image with my scatter plots not aligned with the gantt:

```
# Create figure and axis objects
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8))

# Plot the first graph on the first axis
ax1.barh(df_gantt.Milestone, df_gantt.days_start_to_end, left=df_gantt.start_num, color= "#04AA6D", edgecolor = "Black",zorder=2)
for i in df_gantt.end_num.unique():
    ax1.axvline(x=i,color='black', ls=':', lw=1.5,zorder=1)
ax1.invert_yaxis()
ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax1.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax1.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax1.axvline(x=0,color='grey', ls=':', lw=0.3)

# Create a second axis that shares the same x-axis with the first axis
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# Plot the second graph on the second axis
for i in df.columns:
    sns.stripplot(x=df[i],
                  data=df,
                  color='grey',
                  edgecolor='black',
                  linewidth=1,
                  alpha=0.4,
                  dodge=True,
                  zorder=1,
                  ax=ax2)

    ax2.scatter(x=df[i].mean(), y=0, zorder=2, marker="^", s=310, color="white", edgecolor='black', linewidth=2.5)
    ax2.axvline(x=0, color='grey', ls=':', lw=0.3)
    ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax2.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
    ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    ax2.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax2.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.xlim([-5, 70])

plt.show()
```

Comment: What are you trying to represent by this? Gantt charts represent time (one axis) across dependencies, while scatter plots are used to show correlation on across multiple axis... If you want to show points in time along the Gantt, then there would be a better way to do that with just vertical line markers

Comment: The Gantt is the theoretical process while the scatter points are the actual timestamp at the end of the process step. This is to visualize how a process is followed through time. 
In reality my process is longer and I have outliers plus I am normalizing each point relatively to each process step due date because some have exceptions etc. But it helps giving an overall idea of how well this is respected vs how it was designed initially

Comment: "Actual timestamps" along a horizontal time axis can just be vertical lines. I'm confused what needs to be scattered here. Or, you can use a candlestick chart to denote estimated time expansion of tasks, with associated outliers

Comment: Vertical lines would be more difficult to read when comparing several sub-categories and don't reflect on the density, but the candlestick chart sounds even better actually for all my use cases. I will give it a shot thanks

Comment: Box plot is what I meant, actually. Candlestick is more used in financial data

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes I tried to implement it with
for n, colname in enumerate(df2.columns, 1):
    serie = df2[colname]
    sns.boxplot(data=df, x=serie, y=n)
But I have an error code AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all' 
Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: Please create a new post with your code and errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need 2 axes to reproduce the desired figure.

Here is a working example:

```py
# From here ...
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8))

ax1.barh(df_gantt.Milestone, df_gantt.days_start_to_end, left=df_gantt.start_num, color= "#04AA6D", edgecolor = "Black",zorder=2)

for i in df_gantt.end_num.unique():
    ax1.axvline(x=i, color='black', ls=':', lw=1.5,zorder=1)
    
ax1.axvline(x=0, color='grey', ls=':', lw=0.3)

# ... to here you had it

# Simply create the triangle scatter and stripplot on the same axis. 
# orient="h" and native_scale=True are important param for the desired look
stripplot_kwargs = dict(orient="h", native_scale=True, color='grey', edgecolor='black', linewidth=1, alpha=0.4)

for n, colname in enumerate(df.columns, 1): 
    serie = df[colname]
    sns.stripplot(x=serie, y=n, **stripplot_kwargs)
    ax1.scatter(x=serie.mean(), y=n, zorder=2, marker="^", s=310, color="white", edgecolor='black', linewidth=2.5)

# Invert the axis and remove axis frame
ax1.invert_yaxis()
ax1.axis("off")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the insights! Unfortunately I have the error "AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'" which pop up at the line ax1 = sns.stripplot(x=serie, y=n, **stripplot_kwargs)
I re-used exactly the same otherwise which is odd, also upgraded my seaborn in case but still have this error

Comment: @AdD I reuse the exact code you put to create the 2 dataframes + the exact code I put as "working example" and it works well on my side. Which version of `matplotlib` and `seaborn` are you using ?

Comment: I initially tried to run it on Google Colab this is where I got the error but I just wrote it on Streamlit and I can see the result working beautifully there! 
My Google Colab lib versions are Seaborn in 0.11.2 and matplotlib in 3.5.3, another Python mystery, but thank you very much for the help here